# Signed byte array to UIImage

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, arrays, nsdata

I am trying to display a picture from a byte-array produced by a web service. Printing out a description it looks like this:
("-119",80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,3 ...  )
From the header it is clear that it's a png encoded in signed integers. It is an __NSCFArray having __NSCFNumber elements.

My code in Objective-C (based on much googling):

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)myImageArray length [myImageArray count]];
UIImage *arrayImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

I receive a null UIImage pointer.
I also tried to converting it to unsigned NSNumbers first and then passing it to NSData, though perhaps I did not do this correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read the same image in from a file and confirm the NSData contents is correct.

Comment: From a webservice? How was the data then? What kind? what's the length of it? What's `imageArray` and what's `myImageArray`? What's the length of array? If it's not too long (and the content image not "offensive or private), you may copy it here and we may find your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your Help. I was able to solve with the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply cast an `NSArray` of `NSNumber` into binary data. Both `NSArray` and `NSNumber` are objects; they have their own headers and internal structure that is not the same as the original string of bytes. You'll need to convert it byte-by-byte with something along these lines:

```
NSArray *bytes = @[@1, @2, @3];
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:bytes.count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < bytes.count; i++) {
    char value = [bytes[i] charValue];
    [data replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1) withBytes:&value];
}
```

`char` is a signed `int8_t`, which appears to be the kind of data you're working with. It is often used to mean "an ASCII character," but in C it is commonly also used to mean "byte."

Comment: Thank you! That worked! How would you reverse this process?